When a proton and neutron fuse in Big Bang Nucleosynthesis, do they emit a virtual neutral pion that emits two photons?
In Big Bang Nucleosynthesis, when a proton and neutron fuse to form a deuteron, how does the binding energy get shed? The binding is remanent strong nuclear force so does it emit a virtual neutral pion, which then decays to two real photons? I've seen replies that say a single photon gets emitted but I don't understand that. A strong force interaction isn't electromagnetic. I would like to understand the individual steps (e.g., Feynman diagram). Thanks in advance.

have you compared the binding energy of the deuteron to the mass of the neutral pion? You must, in your question.

If it's a virtual pion in a Feynman diagram, can't it take on any mass? I'm not saying it's a real pion. Do you believe the proton and neutron have an electromagnetic interaction and emit a single photon?

Yes their quarks do, as in standard nuclear physics. Believe?

OK. I guess I can't think of this in terms of a simple Feynman diagram.

You cannot think of nuclear binding this way, as you were instructed.
